# Convergence of binomial probability

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a condition that determines a binomial probability $\rho_n \in (0,1)$. I try to prove that it approaches $1/2$ when $n$ grows without limit. Numerical exercises seem to support my efforts. Also a heuristic normal approximation seems consistent with the idea.

The following condition, where the left hand side is the upper 'half' of the cumulative distribution of a binomial, and the right hand side a parameter $v < \frac{1}{2}$, determines $\rho_n$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n} ^{2n-1} {2n-1 \choose k} \rho_n^k \left(1-\rho_n \right)^{2n-1-k} = v   \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)
\end{align}

The solution to $\rho_n$ in Equation (1) is always unique in the range of $(0,1)$ for each pair of $v$ and $n$.

I checked some numerical results. They confirm that $\rho_n$ approaches to 0.5 when $n$ goes to infinity. I used Mathematica.

The heuristics that I used is that if $X_{2n-1}$ is a binomial random variable with the success probability $\rho_n$, then the left hand side of (1) is $Pr\left(X_{2n-1} \geq n\right)$. When $n$ is large, this is about $Pr \left( Z \geq \frac{n-\rho (2n-1)}{\rho \left(1-\rho\right)\sqrt{(2n-1)} } \right)$ where $\rho$ is the limit of $\rho_n$ and $Z$ is the standardised normal distribution. The probability is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
Pr \left( Z \geq \frac{n\left(1 -\rho (2-1/n) \right)}{\rho \left(1-\rho \right)\sqrt{(2n-1)}} \right)
\end{equation}

which is approximately

\begin{equation}
Pr \left( Z \geq 
\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(1 - 2 \rho \right) }{\rho \left(1-\rho\right)\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{equation}

From this expression it seems that any other value of $\rho$ but one half would be inconsistent with the defining condition (1) for $\rho_n$ for large $n$. It is also a little mysterious to me why $\rho_n$ would go to one half regardless of the value of $v < \frac{1}{2}$.

I wonder if my reasoning above is sound, and how should I proceed to a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it rigorous, we need Lyapunov's Central Limit Theorem. (I replaced $\rho_n$ by $p_n$ and $\rho$ by $p$.)

Let $\{Z_{ni} : 1\le i\le 2n-1\}$ be a triangular array of independent random variables, such that for each $i,$ the $Z_{ni}$'s are iid $Ber(p_n).$ Define $$Y_{ni} = \frac{Z_{ni} - p_n}{\sqrt{2n-1}}, \text{ for } 1\le i\le 2n-1.$$ Then, $$E(Y_{ni})=0, s_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} E(Y_{ni})^2 = p_n(1-p_n)$$
and $$\tau_n = s_n^{-3} \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} E|Y_{ni}^3| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}} \frac{p_n^2 + (1-p_n)^2}{\sqrt{p_n(1-p_n)}}.$$
If we assume that $p_n\to p,$ then $s_n^2 \to p(1-p)$ and $\tau_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Hence, by Lyapunov's Central Limit theorem, we can say that $$S_n = s_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} Y_{ni} \Rightarrow N(0, 1).$$

Now, in your problem we have $$v = \Pr(X_{2n-1}\geq n) = \Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} Y_{ni} \geq \frac{n-(2n-1)p_n}{\sqrt{2n-1}} \right),$$ 
i.e. $$v = \Pr\left(S_n \ge a_n\right) \text{ where } a_n= \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n-1}} \frac{1-2p_n + p_n/n}{\sqrt{p_n(1-p_n)}}.$$
Now, although $S_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1),$ the sequence $a_n$ blows up to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on whether $p<1/2$ or $p>1/2.$ The only case where it does not happen is when $p_n=1/2$ for each $n\ge 1.$ In this case $\Pr(S_n\ge a_n)=v = \Pr(X_{2n-1}\ge n)=1/2$ for each $n\ge 1.$

However, we can scale by one more factor or $\sqrt{n}$. Note that $S_n\Rightarrow Z\sim N(0,1)$ implies that $(2n-1)^{-1/2} S_n \Rightarrow Z' \sim \delta_0,$ (i.e. $Z'$ is degenerate at $0$).  Then, $$v = \Pr\left((2n-1)^{-1/2} S_n \geq \frac{n(1-2p_n)+p_n}{(2n-1)s_n}\right)\to \Pr\left(Z' \ge \frac{1-2p}{2\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right),$$ and the last probability is $0$ if $p<1/2$ and $1$ if $p\ge 1/2.$

Conclusion: The last paragraph suggests that if $v\neq 0,\frac{1}{2},$ or $1,$ the sequence $p_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Everything is crystal clear. However I do not quite follow the conclusion. It seems that you proved the limit is 1/2 but the conclusion says no. Since $p_n$  can be viewed as a bounded  sequence  of  real  numbers, it  must have  a convergent subsequence which ensures for large enough $n$, $p_n$ has some limit. (by the  Bolzano-Weierstrass  Theorem)

Comment: $p_n$ necessarily has a convergent subsequence. But that does not imply that the whole sequence $p_n$ converges. And I showed that apart from the simple case that $p_n=1/2$ for all but finitely many $n,$ the sequence $\Pr(X_{2n-1}\geq n)=\Pr(S_n\ge a_n)$ can converge to only $0$ or $1,$ mainly because $a_n$ (as defined above) does not converge to any finite value (unless all but finitely many $p_n$ are equal to $1/2$).

Comment: Thank you for your effort.